# Is there any Russification of the Simple MCQ Drupal 7 module?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Is there any Russification of the [Simple MCQ](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_mcq) Drupal 7 module? How to translate it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is partially translated: [Translate Simple MCQ to Russian](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/ru/translate?project=simple_mcq).

To import the translation that exists into your own site, enable the core **Locale** module and add [**Localization update**](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update).  You can now use the [standard Drupal translation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/locale) site interface to translate the bits that are not translated.

Please help the community by adding your own translations to [Localize.Drupal.org](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/ru/translate?project=simple_mcq)